# how to pass ssm parameter to cloudwatch to monitor ec2 instance state change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-parameter-store, aws-ssm

is it possible to pass EC2 instance-id stored as a parameter in SSM to Cloud-Watch event rule.

EC2 will created by AutoScaling and its Instance-Id will be stored in SSM.
Now I wanted to pass my SSM parameter to CloudWatch to monitor state change of the instance , in place of InstanceId as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-email-instance-state-change/

Comment: @amitd , they are using "any instance" option, for SNS but i wanted to use specific instance id, whose value is stored in SSM

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no direct integration between Cloudwatch Event Rules and the SSM Parameter Store.

You'll have to build some automation to update the rule yourself. The goto solution for this would be a Lambda function that responds to changes in the parameter value and then updates the rule with the value. To trigger this you should be able to use an advanced parameter and [use event bridge to trigger the lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-cwe.html) on parameter value changes.

Comment: but i wanted to monitor ec2 state change of the instance id stored in ssm

Comment: I've tried to tell you there is no direct integration for that and also to describe a way that allows you to build your own - did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: ok , thanks , I have to check event bridge , btw is there a reason this integration is not created by aws ?

Comment: AWS is famously customer driven and will build what customers ask them to build. You can create a support ticket with a feature request and they may implement it - but they usually don't explain why something isn't there ;-)